# MicroStrategy Desktop 11 - grid

Tags: desktop, microstrategy

I have a problem with the simplest grid. I use as a database Sample - superstore.xlsx

and when I put in rows attribute region that's ok, but when I put any of metrics, my layout change from table to this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGVXc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that I've solved this problem by myself :).
If I add an attribute to row and metrics to metrics...I got the bad layout, but if I change the layout to a bar chart, and then change again to the grid...bad layout change to the good layout. It seems that MicroStrategy has a bug on this matter.